# How to get the elevations points from Google maps in C#?

Tags: c#, google-maps-api-3, elevation

I am trying to get the altitudes of all points in a specific Google Map, be it in the UK or the US or just randomly around the world, and then store the altitude data into an Array[x,y] in C#??

I know that Google has something called Elevation map, but it seems that everyone are trying to get the Longitude / Latitude using it, so..
Can anyone give a link to where I can find how to get the Altitude or give an example program for it in C#??

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the rest service of google which returns the elevations base on direction or coordinates here's some code that could guide you in the right way

```
 //builds the URL of the service
 String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/elevtation/xml?address=example"; 
 //gets the xml returned by the service
 XmlTextReader xml = new XmlTextReader(url);
```

From here's you need to parse the xml and store in in whatever element that you want, could be a database, List, Array. etc.

[Here you will found how to call service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/) and all the different ways to consume the service and see which part you need

Comment: Note that you can also use automatic serialization (or deserialization here) if you want to convert from XML or JSON to C# structures.

Answer (score 0):

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;


    public double getElevation(DbGeography point)
    {
        //https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/intro
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations={0},{1}", point.Latitude, point.Longitude));
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream() ?? new MemoryStream()).ReadToEnd();

        var json = JObject.Parse(sr);
        return (double)json.SelectToken("results[0].elevation");
    }
```